# This directory does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github

I have factory reset my computer, and before that, I had my github repositories synced locally to remotely. Now I am trying to add a local repository and it keeps showing: This directory does not appear to be a git repository. All repositories did this. I pasted in the .gitattributes file in, they are all in a file github, and creating a new local repository worked.
[image: GitHub Desktop not adding local repository]

Here is what it looks like after I created a new repository for one of the repositories online that I had, and tried linking them with the URL:
[image: Repository Settings not showing URL option]

It did not show the URL option. Publishing doesn't work because it already exists on GitHub.

Comment: Are you trying to clone a remote repository? `git clone https://github.com/username/repo`. Or are you trying to create a new repository? `git init`. Done!

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, neither. I have the files and the repository both locally and remotely. I have factory reset my computer so now i need to relink them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of adding an existing folder, you should clone your repo to a new one, and start working from said new clone.

See [GitHub Desktop cloning a repository](https://services.github.com/on-demand/github-desktop/clone-repository-github-desktop).

But if you want to use your *existing* folder as a local repo of an existing remote repo, follow [desktop/desktop issue 2883](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2883)

> - Drag an ordinary folder into the app (or use Add Local Repository and choose the folder)
> - You'll get a message saying "This directory does not appear to be a Git repository. Would you like to create a repository here instead?" and the "Add Repository" folder is disabled
> - Click "create a repository here"
> - Select the "Repository -> Repository Settings... -> Remote" option. Enter the URL of your remote repo.

Comment: @VARUNSINGH You should be able to ignore that, and then set the URL of an existing rmeote repo yourself.

Comment: the only options are publish in the Remote tab and ignore files in the ignored files tab

Comment: @VARUNSINGH Then try and close GitHub Desktop, and add the remote URL manually: cd /apth/to/repo; git remote add origin /url. Open GitHub Desktop back up after that.

Comment: 'git is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file. I am doing this on Windows command prompt. Do i need to use Git Bash? It showed the following: _git remote add origin /https://github.com/KnowledgeableKangaroo/supreme-guacamole
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file._

Comment: @VARUNSINGH On Windows, you can simply install https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.18.0.windows.1/Git-2.18.0-64-bit.exe, and then try again, from a new CMD session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177387/discussion-between-varun-singh-and-vonc).

Answer (score 0):

I added `Github for desktop` in the `login items` so that it would boot during mac start. It worked.

System Preferences -> Users and Groups -> Click on the user -> select Login items tab -> Click the plus icon and add `Github for desktop`